# Where is the Chocolatey installation path?

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey

I am looking to find out the current Chocolatey installation path using PowerShell.

Comment: just do `$env:ChocolateyInstall`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is an environment variable set on installation, `ChocolateyInstall`, which is set to `C:\Chocolatey` by default in versions of Chocolatey less than 0.9.8.27. After that, this defaults to `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey`.

**NOTE:** By default, the `C:\ProgramData` folder on Windows is hidden. You will either need to enable hidden files and folders through `Folder Options | View` or you can navigate directly to the path shown above by copy/pasting directly into the Windows Explorer address bar.

In version 0.9.9 of Chocolatey, it actively moves from the old folder location to the new one.

You can also pre-emptively create this environment variable before installing Chocolatey to control where it gets installed if required.

Comment: @TechZilla have you enabled hidden folders?  ProgramData is hidden by default, so you can either enable that through View options in Windows Explorer, or you can take the path that I have shown above and paste it directly into the Windows Explorer address bar and hit enter.

Comment: Yes, even on Windows Server 2008 there is the folder `C:\ProgramData` (hidden).

Answer (score 1):

When you install Chocolatey they add the Chocolatey `/bin` path to your path variable.

In PowerShell:

```
$env:Path
```