# How to find out the location of files of a package installed by chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I would like to find out the location of the files of a package installed by a chocolatey. It seems the installation location is not consistent.

Suppose I run `choco install pycharm`. Is there a choco command to find out the files installed by this package?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235388/where-is-the-chocolatey-installation-path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a Chocolatey command that can help with this no.

During installation of an application, via the Chocolatey package, Chocolatey will attempt to find the installation location of the application, based on the entries made into the registry, or other locations.  Due to the way that some Windows installers work, or how they have been written, this information isn't always available.

That is why sometimes Chocolatey will be able to write out the installation location after installation is complete, and others not.

Assuming that `pycharm` installs as an executable, which is available on the path (full disclosure, I have never used pycharm), you should be able to do something like the following in PowerShell session:

```
&where.exe pycharm
```

And that will list out where the main exe is located.

Comment: What happens if there are 2 installations? one from chocolatey and another installed through the normal installation file? In that case, where.exe may no longer be effective.

Comment: Agreed, this isn't a perfect solution.  If there are multiple locations where an application is installed to, and they are all accessible on the path, then running where.exe will return them both.  In most cases, Chocolatey packages are wrappers around the native installer, so unless someone has changed the defaults, they would be the same location.

Answer (score 1):

The path where the package is installed can be found in Windows **Environment Variables**
ChocolateyToolsLocation => Path